Run IConfiguration .Build() more than once
Can someone clarify once and for all whether running IConfiguration's .Build() more than once is ok or not?  I see the following type of answer in many SO answers but I heard somewhere that you weren't supposed to do this.
We already know that this type of code is generally not needed because of dependency injection but I'm referring to edge cases.  The following code shows an example.  I've seen another example of using something like this when building a 3rd party library.  Will using something like this introduce bugs or not?
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

// Get url to webservice used for logging.
var c = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
   .Build();

// We use the common services URL to log to a central database.
var u = c[key: "MyCommonService:Url"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("MyCommonService:Url");
var url = new Uri(u);
LoggingHelper.Configure(url, c["Logging:LogLevel:Default"]);



try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.Configure<Config>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ToastService>();
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();
    ...
    etc
    ...
    var app = builder.Build();


Just to clarify: I first thought you meant calling Build() more than once on the same builder. But that's not the case, right?

If I am not mistaken, then I have seen something like this in the examples for logging the "bootstrap" process in console apps ...

I think it's still a bit ambivalent what you are actually asking. But if you ask whether you can have a separate ConfigurationBuilder instance and build() that in addition to the one that's automatically build within the Host without issues, then yes. Every Builder register's it's own providers which populate a Dictionary within each Provider. The IConfiguration interface then just gives you a way to access all those dictionaries from a single point. As provider instances are created per ConfiguationBuilder you have separate instances of the dictionaries, so there is no collision.

@Mushroomator build() returns an IConfigurationRoot, you would think there would only be one of these per app, but I guess not.

Hi @PostImpatica, Using .Build() more than once is acceptable. But in most cases, it's better to stick to a single build unless you have a specific need to access configuration before the main builder is set up.

Apparently there are two solid answers to the combined question I asked.
IConfiguration pre-setup
The general consensus is that the code I show above works fine.
IConfiguration from a library
The opposite is true for a library, please
see This answer.
